# In raid, but does not appear to be an md device?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-drive, raid, software-raid

Am running Ubuntu 16.04 and setup a raid with 2 4tb hdd's. When I run this:

```
sudo cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [raid1] [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10] 
md0 : active raid1 sda[0] sdb[1]
      3906887488 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]
      bitmap: 0/30 pages [0KB], 65536KB chunk

unused devices: <none>
```

Yet, when I run this:

```
sudo mdadm --detail /mnt/md0
mdadm: /mnt/md0 does not appear to be an md device
```

So I am confused. It is in raid, but not with mdadm? How do I ensure that I have this raid setup correctly?

Additionally, how can I ensure this is mounted correctly? Lots to read on the net, but first time doing this in Linux.

Comment: How'd you set up the raid? Anything to do with `dmraid`? Anything in `/dev/mapper/` or any `/dev/dm*`?

Comment: Another setup style (dmraid) uses an assembled "name" in `/dev/mapper/` but it looks like yours should be `/dev/md#` or in `/dev/md/` I haven't found a simple command to check for sure, unfortunately. `man mdadm` has a section for "DEVICE NAMES" at the end, a few options

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably wanted to write `/dev/md0` and not `/mnt/md0`.

Device files are always generated in the `/dev` folder while `/mnt` is generally used to only mount them (connect the storage device content to the current filesystem).

Comment: But I have no md0 or mnt folder in the dev folder.

Comment: There shouldn't be `mnt` folder inside `/dev`, just `md0` device file. Try searching the folder automatically then, like `find /dev -type b -iname md*`

Comment: Cool, there is that device file in the dev/ folder. Now when I run `sudo mdadm --detail /mnt/md0`, it gives me the right info. Thanks for that. Now in my search, I am wondering if raid if better that a simple sync? Any thoughts on that?

Comment: So now though, do I need to mount this or something?

Comment: Yes, to use the device, you have to mount it or add it to `fstab`( https://askubuntu.com/q/417286/593050 ). The raid device behaves like normal harddisk. I'm not sure what you mean by 'raid better than simple sync'. It will depend on your use-case and is outside of the scope of the current question.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way for me to tell if it is already mounted? I mean, I can access the space that should be available there.

Comment: Use `df` or plain `mount`, it will show you. But honestly, you'd get answer for that faster here: http://lmgtfy.com/?q=show+currently+mounted+drives+in+linux